# Как настроить маршрутизацию между мостами в mikrotik?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, mikrotik

Я создал два моста

snet где у меня живут порты серверов
cnet где у меня все клиентские порты и wlan интерфейсы

snet имеет подсеть 10.0.0.0
cnet имеет подсеть 10.0.1.0

Соответственно хочу чтобы клиенты из сети 10.0.1.0 видели сервера в сети 10.0.0.0
Пока из сети 10.0.0.0 видно только 10.0.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте свои настройки `/ip firewall` (ну и `/ip route` до кучи)

По-умолчанию `mikrotik` никак не фильтрует `forward` и все могут общаться со всему.

Comment: а что должно быть прописано в ip route?

Comment: Должны быть автоматически-добавленные роуты 10.0.0.0/netmask via snet, 10.0.1.0/netmask via cnet. А то вдруг у вас там какие-нибудь хитрые правила в rules. Но раз из сети 10.0.0.0 видно 10.0.1.1, куда более вероятна проблема в forward цепочке firewall.

Comment: Такие правила есть

- DAS 
0.0.0.0/0 192.168.1.1 reachable ether1 1   
- DAC 
10.0.0.0/24 snet reachable 0  10.0.0.1 
- DAC 
10.0.1.0/24 cnet reachable 0  10.0.1.1 
- DAC 
192.168.1.0/24 ether1 reachable 0  192.168.1.131 
- DAC 
192.168.88.0/24 bridge reachable 0  192.168.88.1